# Loop HTTP.Get requests in SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I'd like to make multiple `HTTP.Get` requests in a Script Activity, based on the number of rows returned from a LookupRows function.

The issue is that it only makes the `HTTP.Get` request once, for the first record in the rowset. Here's my code:

```javascript
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1");
var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows('Reconciliation Report','Missing',1);
     if(dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) {
          for(var i=0; i<dataRows.length; i++) {
            var createInteractions = HTTP.Get('http://pages.company.com/ProcessMissing');
        }
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that looping `HTTP.Get` requests in SSJS is either broken or not supported. However, I can simply make a POST request instead and this works:

```javascript
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1");
var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows('Reconciliation Report','Missing',1);
     if(dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) {
          for(var i=0; i<dataRows.length; i++) {
            var createInteractions = HTTP.Post('http://pages.company.com/ProcessMissing');
        }
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this isn't a limitation now: 
Tested the loop with full object logging for success and errors to a DE to upto 500 iterations in a script activity and it works.

```
 Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
//Log response object to DE 
var logRows = DataExtension.Init("DEtoLog"); 

//Lookup the get parameters from this DE
var dataRows = DataExtension.Init("GETParametersDE").Rows.Lookup(["hook"], [1]); 

if(dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dataRows.length; i++){
        try{
            var url = "[endpoint]?id="+dataRows[i].SubscriberKey;    

            var result = HTTP.Get(url);
            var jsonObject = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Content);
            var logRow ={
                     "Status" : "Success",
                     "SubscriberKey" : jsonObject.identity.email,
                     "ID": jsonObject.identity.id,
                     "JSONresponse": result.Content
                    }

                logRows.Rows.Add(logRow);
        }         

        catch(e){

            var logRow ={
                 "Status" : "ERROR",
                 "ErrorMsg" : Stringify(e) 
                }

                logRows.Rows.Add(logRow);      
        }
    }
}
```

Note in a cloudpage, the same code resulted in the error

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. -
>   from mscorlib

after about 150 requests.
Looks like a built-in limitation to ASP.Net HTTPHandler according to https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/817266/prb-system-threading-threadabortexception-error-message-when-you-use-s