# Whats the simplest way to make Rest API Calls from Salesforce to Marketing Cloud without involving App Center

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I wish to make Rest API Calls to Marketing Cloud for an update in Salesforce instance sending emails through Marketing cloud to Customers.

When I researched on how to implement it, It has a basic requirement of access token, which can be generated with the help client Id and Client Secret, which in turn can only be generated through App Center.

Is there any other way to get client Id and client secret for generating access token to make Rest API Calls without involving App Center.

Please suggest.

Comment: There's no way to get a ClientID and ClientSecret without going through App Center. Could you say why that would be an issue as it takes ten minutes and you don't have to revisit the step. Is there a reason you've settled using the REST API in place of other less code-y options? Do you have the connector installed? Would Salesforce Triggered Sends or Journey Builder Events for CRM not work here?

Comment: Hi Andrew, Good Day! Yes I have got the connector installed. We have not yet finalized, if we will go with REST API Calls, actually we are looking for best possible way, to get this functionality up, and also some way where we do not allow marketing cloud to update records in salesforce and get our email trigger to customer after every change to the field in salesforce record. With using Journey builder I have reset this field to null after the email activity through update activity.

Answer (score 1):

You explained that you would like to make 'an update in Salesforce instance sending emails through Marketing cloud'. I assume you are referring to creating or updating records in Sales Cloud objects at the time an email is sent.

If that's your intention, I'd recommend you consider using the `CreateSalesforceObject()` or `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject()` [Salesforce AMPscript functions](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/). These are effectively wrappers for the Sales Cloud REST API methods and using these AMPscript functions does not count towards your Sales Cloud REST API limit.

However, bear in mind that you need to be aware of [record lock concurrency](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160622/createsalesforceobject-ampscript-function-and-record-locking-concurrency) which may apply in certain scenarios where there are relationships to other Sales Cloud objects in the record you are creating or updating. But whether you are using AMPscript or the REST API, you are going to run into the same lock contention issues, so you just need to aware of this.

Comment: Thanks Eliot, Greetings! , actually I  want to send email after update on lead record in salesforce, and email should go from SFMC. This update can take place multiple times on the same record, and every time we want to send email to customer. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Then a Salesforce AMPscript function in your email is definitely the way to go, but just be mindful of record lock concurrency as I referenced earlier, which may or may not apply to your scenario.

Comment: Using AMPscript, will there be any update by SFMC on Records in Salesforce instance. Because we do not want SFMC to make changes to records in Salesforce instance. Thanks Eliot.

Comment: Yes of course there will be an update on records. In your question, you asked how to use Marketing Cloud to make 'an update in Salesforce instance'. If this isn't what you want, please clarify your question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use REST API, you'll have to use App Center. If not, you can use SOAP API to send emails.